# Spark-submit not finding main class although it does exist in the jar file

Tags: apache-spark

First: here is the application jar file to be submitted:

```
$ls -rlta /shared/ysgood/target/yardstick-spark-uber-0.0.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 steve  staff  138611565 Aug  6 01:41 /shared/ysgood/target/yardstick-spark-uber-0.0.1.jar
```

Here is the class to be submitted:

```
01:55:02/ysgood $jar -tvf target/yardstick-spark-uber-0.0.1.jar | grep SparkCoreRDDBenchmark.class
 15091 Thu Aug 06 01:36:30 PDT 2015 org/yardstick/spark/SparkCoreRDDBenchmark.class
```

Here is the attempt at submitting:

```
$spark-submit --master $MASTER --class org.yardstick.spark.SparkCoreRDDBenchmark target/yardstick-spark-uber-0.0.1.jar 

NOTE: SPARK_PREPEND_CLASSES is set, placing locally compiled Spark classes ahead of assembly.
Error: Cannot load main class from JAR 
file:/shared/ysgood/org.yardstick.spark.SparkCoreRDDBenchmark
```

Regarding the error: notice the path to the jar is incorrect: the following

> /shared/ysgood/org.yardstick.spark.SparkCoreRDDBenchmark

does not make sense: it is missing the path to the jar file

> target/yardstick-spark-uber-0.0.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

After -class you have to put the package of your main class not the path to the main class. So check if in your code the SparkCoreRDDBenchmark class is in the package org.yardstick.spark.
If it is, then try running your jar without Spark, see if you get the error Cannot load main class. Maybe there where some problems, when the jar was created.
Good luck!

Comment: I did not specify the "folder" in either parameter - so uncertain what you mean. The --class is definitely correct.  The <jar file path>  should be correct as well: from `spark-submit --help`:   `Usage: spark-submit [options] <app jar | python file>` . Finally: this is not an executable jar file - but does not need to be - given the `--class` parameter was specified.

Comment: By folder, I was referring to the path where your main class is.  So  --class package.MainClass. I was thinking maybe after --class you have the main class package wrong. What happens if you run spark-submit from /shared/ysgood/target/ or give the whole path to the jar file /shared/ysgood/target/yardstick-spark-uber-0.0.1.jar ?

Comment: I did try the fully qualified path to the jar file and made no difference. The package name is correct:  you can see that verified in the OP