# Why does spark-submit fail to deploy to YARN?

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I'm running a simple java application in spark, however when I try to submit the application, it shows cannot load main class from Jar file.
Here is a snapshot of the error.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should add more details to your question. Which version of Spark are you using? What where the steps to get this error. And please add the error message as text, formatted as code to your question. Use the `edit` link below. Related: [Spark-submit not finding main class although it does exist in the jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851214/spark-submit-not-finding-main-class-although-it-does-exist-in-the-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the `--class` and `--master` arguments.

```
spark-submit --master yarn-client --class spark.examples.SimpleApp /root/simple-project-1.0.jar hdfs://myserver1:8020/user/root/hackrfoe.txt
```